# How do I store multiple jQuery selectors in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Obviously it's a good idea to store jQuery selectors in variables if they are used more than once (*not* a good idea if used only once).

My question is, how do you store multiple selectors, that are used interchangeably, in a variable.

For instance, let's say I select `$('#object1, #object2)`, then later on I select `$('#object1'). How would I create a variable that can be combined with other variables to create multiple selectors.

If I were to write it like this:

```
var object1 = "#object1";
var object2 = "#object2";

$(object1  + "," + object2);
```

I would only be referencing the string `#object1`, and not the actual selector.

So how do I store multiple selectors in variables, so they can be used interchangeably?

Comment: What's wrong with that code?  I think it would work just fine.

Comment: it's storing just a string as a var, not the actual selector.

Comment: To be precise, the selector *is* the string, while what you're referring to is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not the `selector string`, the problem is the **query** of the DOM element. "Problem" means, it's expensive. That is why you should only query an element once and store a reference to it.

```
var object1 = $('#object1'),
    object2 = $('#object2');

object1.some_method();
```

**update**

In reference to your comment:

jQuery offers the `.add()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/add/)</sup>  method which allows to concat jQuery objects:

```
object1.add(object2).method();
```

Comment: That's easy enough to do, but how would you apply `some_method();` to `#object1` and `#object2` ?

Answer (score 3):

Not completely sure I understand what you mean.  You want to store the jQuery objects so you don't have to continually search for them like some sort of cache?

```
var cache = new Object();
cache['#object1'] = $('#object1');
cache['#object2'] = $('#object2');
```

To retrieve the jQuery values, you'd merely have to call `cache['#object1']`.

Comment: I'd recommend that you use the Object literal, `{}` to initialize an object rather than creating a new instance of Object. Eg. `var cache = {};`. This executes faster and saves a few bytes.

Comment: Thought it was the same.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var object1 = $('#object1'), object2 = $('#object2');

object1.add(object2).addClass('couple');
```

Or,

```
var multiple = [object1[0], object2[0], ...];

$(multiple).addClass('party');
```

Answer (score 0):

a selector is a string when passed to the $() fn. returns a collection of Elements that match the selector. So there is nothing wrong with this code.

Your code can also be written as,

```
var object1 = "#object1",
    object2 = "#object2";

$(object1).add(object2).doSomething();
```

or it can be further optimized as,

```
var object1 = $('#object1'),
    object2 = $('#object2');

object1.add(object2).doSomething();
```

where `doSomething` can be a jQuery or jQuery plugin defined method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the easy way.

```
var severalVar = 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6';
 $(severalVar).hide()
```